# Shut off UITableView autosize

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have a table view which is autosizing to the full frame of the view it is in.  I don't want it to stretch.  I've shut off all of the bars in AutoSizing in Interface Builder but to no avail.  How can I shut off autosizing and stretching in IB?

Comment: IB can be a pain with UITableView sizing. Have you considered doing this programmatically, initializing the tableView with a style and then setting the frame to a specified frame with CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found to be the best answer is to just create the UITableView from code and size it there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and tried everything to no avail. Maybe this isn't the most elegant answer, but my solution was to make a UIView which is the size I want for the table view and then add the table view as a subview.

Bit hacky, but worked for me!